# Getting data from stream for later use

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, stream

i'm trying to get data out of a stream.

```js
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
        console.log(results)
  });

console.log(results);
```

The result is first one empty [] and after that the data of the csv.

```
[]
[ { '0': '10-01-2020 14:37:20',
    '1': '10-01-2020 18:17:42',
    '2': '13222',
    '3': '00',
    '4': '3.67',
    '5': '36.73',
    '6': '',
    '7': 'Default' },
  { '0': '10-01-2020 09:02:00',
    '1': '10-01-2020 14:02:20',
    '2': '18020',
    '3': '00',
    '4': '5.01',
    '5': '50.06',
    '6': '',
    '7': 'Default' } ]
```

I want to modify the data in `result` later in the program.

I think i'm missing some basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with the code. You have console statements twice. One at the end which is what is printing empty array.

`createReadStream` is an async operation so the console on the `end` listener is getting triggered afterwards.

If you remove the last console statement it will show the results as expected.

Comment: Thanks, just needed the reminder, that Javascript is async. Thank you!

Comment: please mark it as answer for other people's reference.